# OAuth 2.0 Auth Code w/ PKCE: what if attacker intercepts code and uses app backend (client) as proxy to retrieve access token?

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, pkce

Consider a typical Web app with a frontend and backend that uses OAuth 2.0 Auth Code Flow w/ PKCE. The backend is the OAuth 2.0 client communicating with the auth server.

Suppose an attacker intercepts the auth `code` upon user login success. The attacker sends the code to the backend to retrieve an access token, in lieu of the legitimate frontend.

In order words, the attacker inserts themselves at the beginning of the token part of the OAuth auth code flow (before step 1 below):

1. upon user login success and redirect, the user's browser accesses the app backend's token endpoint with `code` to retrieve `access_token`

   - Instead of the user's browser, the attacker accesses the app backend's token endpoint instead
2. the backend calls the auth server to exchange `code` for `access_token`, including `code_verifier` in the request to the auth server as required by PKCE
3. the backend passes `access_token` to the frontend

   - Instead of being passed to the legit frontend, it's passed to the attacker instead

**What prevents this attack?**

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70233642/1232944), which says that if both the attacker and the legit frontend access the client's token endpoint with the same auth `code`, then the auth server revokes already-issued tokens. (recall that OAuth client = app backend.) This doesn't feel totally satisfying to me, since:

- Suppose the attacker is first to access the client's token endpoint. Then, what if the legit frontend fails to access this endpoint (or takes a long time)? The attacker ends up with a valid access token for an extended period.
- Suppose the attacker is 2nd to access the client's token endpoint. Does OAuth 2.0 require the auth server to refuse to issue a 2nd token for the same `code`?